# Count rows, where only specific columns are True

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a boolean dataframe. Where each row is, let us say a "classroom", and each column header is a "student_id". The classroom is set as the index, and I simply want to know the following:

- For various groupings (of student_ids), how many times do they, and ONLY they share a classroom.

The dataframe looks something like the following:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'classroom_id':[1,2,3,4], 'student_1':[True,True,True,True], 'student_2':[True,True,False,False], 'student_3':[True,False,False,False], 'student_4':[False,False,False,True]})

df = df.set_index('classroom_id')
```

I just don't quite know how to query what I want, which is to ask, for example:

> How many times is student_1 and student_2 the ONLY true values?

or

> How many times is student_1 and student_2 the ONLY students in a classroom?

expected result:

```
1 (classroom 2)
```

But, I don't want it to return:

```
2 (classroom 1 and classroom 2)
```

I just don't know the correct query to put in for pandas for this...
Let me know if there are any questions, especially over things that I did not make clear enough.

Comment: Looks like you might find [`pandas.where()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) useful

Comment: If you search in your browser for "Pandas conditional tutorial", you'll find references that can explain this much better than we can manage here.

Comment: I am voting to close this question, due to the lack of effort placed attempting to solve the problem prior to posting.  I feel that it is unfortunate for you, that the answer has been provided.  Do you have any idea as to how to apply the answer given to similar scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this using boolean indexing:

```
df[df['student_1'] & df['student_2'] & (df.sum(1) == 2)]
```

Output:

```
              student_1  student_2  student_3  student_4
classroom_id                                            
2                  True       True      False      False
```

And, getting the count, you can use `shape`:

```
df[df['student_1'] & df['student_2'] & (df.sum(1) == 2)].shape[0]
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: Gig'em! Class of '94.   Geez that year gets getting older and older.

Comment: It's nuts! Thanks for the comment!

Comment: oh and of course gig em!

Comment: I ended up using this and in-cooperated it into a VERY helpful function. Thanks and gig em!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'classroom_id':[1,2,3,4], 'student_1':[True,True,True,True], 'student_2':[True,True,False,False], 'student_3':[True,False,False,False], 'student_4':[False,False,False,True]})
df = df.set_index('classroom_id')

group_of_students = ["student_1","student_2"]    # list the students you want to group together

cond1 = df[group_of_students].all(axis=1)    # check for classrooms where these students all have True
cond2 = ~df.drop(group_of_students, axis=1).any(axis=1)    # check for classrooms where all other students have False
df[cond1 & cond2]    # filter df based on cond1 AND cond2
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment and the time spent answering. I was able to use this, and did work for my problem. Thanks agian.